# Compare the mean of two independent samples (equal size)

Tags: statistical-significance, spss

I would like to check whether there are statistically significant difference between women and men in the use of the Internet. I have a data for 144 countries about the use of the Internet by women and the use of the Internet by men (expressed in percentage of total population). Hence, n1 = 144 and n2 = 144. Which test in SPSS is appropriate for this analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You provide little information about the shape of the data. I will crawl far out onto a speculative limb, trying to imagine what you have. I suppose data consist of 144 *pairs* of scores. If I'm somewhere near close, maybe you have your answer. If not, you can provide numerical/graphical
data summaries (as part of your Question), explaining any doubts about what I show below, and maybe someone can give a better-informed answer. [Also, I do not use SPSS and will show output from R, but the crucial procedures I show here should be also available in SPSS.]

Sampling and computations in R.

```
set.seed(2021)
w = 80*rbeta(144, 4,5)
m = w + 45*(rbeta(144, 5,5) - .35)
```

Numerical summaries:

```
summary(w)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  8.723  25.027  33.701  33.960  42.380  62.391 
summary(m)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.325  31.526  41.131  41.281  50.558  76.597 

d = m-w
summary(d);  length(d);  sd(d)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -8.611   2.760   7.444   7.321  12.523  22.594 
[1] 144        # sample size (nr. of differences)
[1] 7.046872   # SD of differences.
```

A histogram of the differences shows more positive differences than
negative ones. Tick marks below the histogram (made with 'rug') show
the exact values of the 144 differences.

```
hdr = "144 Countries: Diff in Pct Internet Use"
hist(d, prob=T, br=20, col="skyblue2", main=hdr) 
rug(d)
```

[image]

The data are not obviously normal, but a Shapiro-Wilk test does not
reject the possibility that the population of differences may be normal
(P-value well above 5%).

```
shapiro.test(d)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  d
W = 0.99024, p-value = 0.4169
```

One expects that men and women in the same country may have roughly
the same access to the Internet. Ordinarily, paired data are associated.

We find a positive correlation between vectors `m` and `w`.

```
cor(m, w)
[1] 0.8619649
```

A scatterplot of `m` against `w` shows a strong positive association.
That most of the points lie above the 45-degree line (slope 1 through the origin), indicates most difference `d = m-w` are positive; more Internet
usage by men in my fake data.

```
 plot(w, m, pch=20);  abline(0, 1, col="blue")
```

[image]

A one-sample t test on differences (as below) is the same as a paired t
test of the differences. It confirms that the sample mean difference is
significantly above $0.$ (P-value almost $0.)$

```
t.test(d)

        One Sample t-test

data:  d
t = 12.467, df = 143, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 6.160184 8.481767
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 7.320975
```

*Note:* If the histogram of the differences had shown marked differences
or far outliers (either positive or negative), then me might have
decided to use a nonparametric Wilcoxon signed rank test to see whether
the sample median of the `d`s is significantly greater than $0.$ (But is not proper statistical procedure to do both tests and pick the one with the smaller P-value.)

```
wilcox.test(d)

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with continuity correction

data:  d
V = 9680, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
```